# An error occurred while updating the selected review(s)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, review, third-party-module

I suspect it to be caused by one of the modules I recently installed, everytime I try to save a product review I get that message: `An error occurred while updating the selected review(s)`. Any idea where it's coming from? Anyone ever had that problem?

Here's the log:

```
  2015-05-01T20:03:56+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: SQLSTATE[23000]: 
  Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`database_name`.`salesrule_website`, CONSTRAINT `FK_SALESRULE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `core_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE )
    Trace: #0 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
    #1 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
    #2 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
    #3 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
    #4 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
    #5 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1910): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sa...', Array)
    #6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(137): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('salesrule_websi...', Array, Array)
    #7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Rule.php(116): Mage_Rule_Model_Resource_Abstract->bindRuleToEntity('258', Array, 'website')
    #8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(463): Mage_SalesRule_Model_Resource_Rule->_afterSave(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))
    #9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule))
    #10 /public_html/app/code/community/QS/Notification/Model/Notification.php(121): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
    #11 /public_html/app/code/community/QS/Notification/Model/Review.php(67): QS_Notification_Model_Notification->createCartRule(Object(Varien_Object))
    #12 /public_html/app/code/community/QS/Notification/Model/Review/Observer.php(222): QS_Notification_Model_Review->sendNotification('ilonasoboleva@c...', Array, '2818')
    #13 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): QS_Notification_Model_Review_Observer->catchReviewAfterSave(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(QS_Notification_Model_Review_Observer), 'catchReviewAfte...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
    #15 /public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('review_save_aft...', Array)
    #16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('review_save_aft...', Array)
    #17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
    #18 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/ReviewController.php(130): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
    #19 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_ReviewController->saveAction()
    #20 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('save')
    #21 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
    #22 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
    #23 /public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
    #24 /public_html/index.php(95): Mage::run('', 'store')
    #25 {main}
```

One more edit: I suspect [this module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-order-log.html) to be the cause, I have installed 3 modules this week, that's the only one that would need to look at the website_ID

Comment: if it's due to a module you've installed we can't reproduct the error. Please specify at least which module

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I was expecting this response ;) - I've uninstalled everything but the problem comes from the tables that were created with the modules. I have no idea which module it is though...

Answer (score 1):

The error says:

You try to save a data set into `salesrule_website` without satisfying the FK `FK_SALESRULE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID_CORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` which  means, that you don't have a website set.

Whatever this is caused by, I think you have to dig into the code, I recommend xdebug to check, why no website_id is set on your data set.

Comment: Or try blackfire.io to see what code is touching the request (yes, I'm a huge Blackfire fan now)

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be a problem with one of your module

According to the stacks information you gave us, I would bet on the Module Notification within the namespace QS.
(QS/Notification)
QS seems to be QuartSoft, do you have any module from QuartSoft ?
Does it ring you a bell?
try to disable it and check if it's working..

Probably a compatibility problem.. 
The message you gave us seems to a database conflict on a cascade delete..

Comment: maybe you have one of this module installed http://store.quartsoft.com/products/  ?

Comment: You're right, it is [QuarterSoft] (http://store.quartsoft.com/discount-for-review). But I've had that module for over 2 years now, it's not the one causing the damage :(

Comment: Does not matter, there could be multiple reasons . try to unable it just for the test.. in your stack trace this is the latest module called.. are you familiar with debuggin step by step with php ?

Comment: Ok Boss ;) I disabled it, cleared all cache & still causing the problem. It is disabled & I still see QS/Notification in exception.log - same message appears

Comment: Well this is weird.. because if it would be disable you should not see it in the logs.. The best would be to put a breakpoint on line 121 of the file /public_html/app/code/community/QS/Notification/Model/Notification.php to see what's going on from there, but I guess you don't have a debugger installed on the environnement where you have this issue ?